# Share session between Express and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session

I have a Web app built with node/Express that includes backend and frontend.
Now I'm moving the frontend to a React app, one page at time.

I'm trying to find a way to **maintain a shared cart between the two apps**, so a user can add item A and B from an Express page, and item C from React page. Cart is stored in the session, but obviously the two apps have a different session (when in the Express backend I `console.log` the sessionID, React's requests have a different sessionID than Express requests).

This is what I've tried, let's say Express has sessionID 111 and React sessionID 222

- User is on Express page
- When he goes to a React page, Express sends over the current sessionID (111) in the URL or as a parameter
- React calls a /setSession endpoint with that sessionID, so Express looks for session 111 and copies the cart items over on session 222

Now React session contains the same cart items of Express session, yay! Problem is that if I now add items in a React page, Express won't know. I'd have to do something similar to the above, to send the session data back to Express.

I could do it but A) it looks complicated and B) won't work if user has the two apps opened in two tabs, items added on Express won't update the React tab (and viceversa).

So what I'd like is Express and React sharing the same session, or part of it, but I'm lost honestly! I know the rule should be "one session, one client" but part of me wants to think there's an easy way to achieve it..

Comment: instead of using url parameter, did you try calling your express backend from your react app to determine the session? using url parameter seems very unsecure in my opinion.

Comment: Yes @JasperBernales, if I understand correctly what you mean by determine the session, I've tried it and the React session is different than the Express session. So If I add item A and B in an Express page, and add item C in React page, I end up with two sessions instead of one cart with items A B and C.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is, when you go to your react app from express, set a cookie to your react app using your auth token for example. then with the authentication token you get your session details. Im able to work on something like this and I was using redis https://redis.com/solutions/use-cases/session-management/

Comment: Yes in the react app I've implemented authentication with JWT, but the problem is still the same: even if the same use is logged in in both apps, React has a different session than Express. Hence if I add item A and B in Express page, then go to React page and add item C, I have two separate sessions, one with items A and B, one with item C.